# How to use multiple conditions to validate form with react final form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I have form inside my react app,
And i would like to use this condition to validate the form before send the data to backend.

```
<div className="card-body">
        <h3 className="mt-2 btn-primary text-center"> Diseño ChatBot </h3>  
          <Form
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            validate={values => {
             const errors = {};
             if (!values.text || !values.link ||!values.image) {                
               errors.error = 'Es necesario cumplimentar uno de estos tres campo: Texto, Imagen, Link';
             } else {errors.error = undefined;}
             return errors;
           }} 
            initialValues={{ title: title, text: text, link: link, link_title: link_title, image: image, image_title: image_title }}
            render={({ handleSubmit, values, errors }) => (
              <form id='editForm' className="row mt-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >                
                <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="inputDescription" className="form-label text-center">
                    <h5> Título </h5>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-11">
                  <Field
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name='title'
                    component="input"                               
                    /> 
                                     
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="inputResponse" className="form-label text-center" >
                    <h5> Texto </h5>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-11">
                  <Field
                    className="form-control"
                    type="textarea"
                    name='text'
                    component="input"
                    
                  />
                
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="link" className="form-label text-center" >
                    <h5> Link </h5>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5">
                  <Field
                    className="form-control"
                    type="link"
                    name="link"
                    component="input"  
                                      
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-1">
                  <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form-label text-center" >
                    <h5> Title Link </h5>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5">
                  <Field
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    name='link_title'
                    component="input"                    
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
                  <label htmlFor="image" className="form-label text-center" >
                    <h5> Image </h5>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5">
                  <Field
                    name="image"
                    type="file"
                    component={UploadImage}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-1">
                  <label htmlFor="image_title" className="form-label text-center" >
                    <h5> Title Image </h5>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5">
                  <Field
                    className="form-control"
                    type="text"
                    name='image_title'
                    component="input"                    
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  {(isCreated && !isVariationsError) &&
                    <div className="alert alert-success" role='alert'>
                      Respuesta EDITADA Correctamente
                    </div>
                  }                  
                </div>
                <div className="buttons text-center">
                  <Volver className={"btn btn-outline-danger me-5 mb-3"} prevStep={prevStep} step={2}/>                  
                  <button className="btn btn-outline-warning me-5 mb-3" onClick={(e) => (e.preventDefault(), openPreview(values))} >Preview</button>
                  <SaveAndEdit className={"btn btn-outline-success me-5 mb-3"} idForm={'editForm'} text={'Guardar Cambios'}/>                  
                  <Cancelar className={"btn btn-outline-dark  me-5 mb-3"} />
                </div>

                {errors.error && <Error meta={errors.error} /> }
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, undefined, 2)}</pre>
                 <pre>{JSON.stringify(errors, undefined, 2)}</pre>
              </form>
            )}
          />
        </div>
```

I have outside the form this Component Error with this:

```
const Error = (meta) => (
    <h3 className="alert alert-danger text-center mt-5">{meta.meta}</h3>   
  );
```

If i use just with one condition like

```
validate={values => {
             const errors = {};
             if (!values.text) {                
               errors.error = 'Es necesario cumplimentar uno de estos tres campo: Texto, Imagen, Link';
             } else {errors.error = undefined;}
             return errors;
           }}
```

works Fine, but if i try to use more conditions inside the conditional, not works.
Any idea to guide me?

Thanks

Comment: You should try to use formik and yup. It makes form validation and cinstructions super easy. Formik: https://formik.org/ Yup: https://github.com/jquense/yup

Comment: Could it be that you're using `&&` (AND) when you're intention is to use `||` (OR)? Your code says, for an error the user must have no `values.text` AND no `values.link` AND no `!values.image`. If any one of those has a value, the error will not show

Comment: I changed && for || because i n my question. AND or OR not works.